# Can't connect to remote ElasticSearch server using local machine's IP Address

Tags: elasticsearch, digital-ocean, remote-access

I can't connect to ElasticSearch on my Digital Ocean droplet using my local machine's IP Address.

- I got the IP Address by: Terminal > `ipconfig getifaddr en0`

   - With that result, let's say: 100.888.777.99
- I logged into my droplet by running: `ssh username@111.222.3.444`
- Updated my UFW Rules by running: `sudo ufw allow 9200 from 100.888.777.99`
- From my local machine I ran: `curl -X GET 'http://111.222.3.444:9200'`
- And received: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 111.222.3.444 port 9200: Operation timed out`

What am I doing wrong?

Things I've tried:

- Changing the network.host variable in **elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml**

   `network.host: 0.0.0.0` (also this a *security risk* since ip addresses are allowed )
- Restarting the server

   `sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch restart`
- Adding more varibles to **elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml**

   `transport.host: localhost`

   `transport.tcp.port: 9300`

   `http.port: 9200`

Comment: For version 7.0.1, adding the below lines worked for me.
`transport.host: localhost`
The rest 2 lines of the last subpoint were already a part of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I changed the UFW Rules to allow all connection to port 9200, I was able to connect to ElasticSearch from my local machine, but without that, it would not connect.

 `sudo ufw allow 9200`

After some deep diving I found the issue was that the IP address that was returned by Terminal wasn't the correct one to use. I had to use the **Public IP Address** which I got from https://www.whatismyip.com/, you can also get this by:

 Terminal > `curl ifconfig.me`

So when I removed the old UFW rule: `9200   ALLOW IN   100.888.777.99`

 And used the Public IP Address: `sudo ufw allow 9200 from Public_IP_Address` it connected.

I'm still not sure why my machine's IP Address doesn't work though...